# OpenGL Vertex Buffer Object not Showing

Tags: c++, opengl

I have changed 3 GLFloat arrays (aka GLfloat[]) into vectors (aka vector) and my triangles stopped working! Here is my init function:

```
void initialize(GLuint &vao) {

// Use a Vertex Array Object
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

Projection = perspective(45.0f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
//ortho(-4.0f/3.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
Model = translate(Model, vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
Model = rotate(Model, 45.0f, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

//pos + textures array
GLuint vboId;
glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vertices_position.size() + texture_coord.size() ) * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices_position.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices_position[0]);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_position.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), texture_coord.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &texture_coord[0]);

//Indices
GLuint eabId;
glGenBuffers(1, &eabId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, eabId);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &indices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//Textures
GLuint textureId;
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
load_image("../squirrel.jpg");

shaderProgram = create_program("../shaders/vert.shader", "../shaders/frag.shader");

//Position attribute
positionAttrId = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttrId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrId);

//Texture attribute
textureCoordId = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texture_coord");
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordId, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid *)(vertices_position.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordId);

modelId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Model");
cameraId = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Camera");
}
```

And below is my render function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

glUniformMatrix4fv(modelId, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Model));
glUniformMatrix4fv(cameraId, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(cam.matrix()));

//VAO
glBindVertexArray(vao);
//glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glUseProgram(0);
```

Comment: What is vertices_position defined as exactly? `std::vector <GLfloat>` or `std::vector <SomeSortOfVec3>`? If it is not an integral type (e.g. `GLfloat`) I can see your use of `.size ()` being an issue. Please include where you declare the variables vertices_position, texture_coord and indices.

Comment: Sure: "vector<GLfloat> vertices_position", same type as indices, and texture_coords.

Comment: That is your problem. Your indices need to be either `GLushort` or `GLuint`, preferably `GLushort` for performance reasons. The API lets you use `GLubyte` as well, but those are not natively supported on most hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using floating-point elements in your Index Buffer Object, that is not a valid data type.

OpenGL requires either `GLubyte` (not hardware accelerated on most desktop GPUs), `GLushort` or `GLuint` indices.

For best performance, you should use an array of `GLushort` and pass `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` as the element type in your call to `glDrawElements (...)`.